# Saving the full-size photo after capturing with camera gives onActivityResult resultCode 0

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I am trying to save the full-size photo after capturing with camera but on onActivityResult it gives me the resultCode 0. I am using a Fileprovider to take the Uri from a File in filepaths.xml. Below you can see my code:

in filepaths.xml:

```
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="my_images/"/>
</paths>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

in the Activity:

```
tempFile = null;
                                File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(),"my_images");
                                tempFile = new File(imagePath, "temp.jpg");
                                try {
                                    tempFile.createNewFile();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
Log.d("PostItemActivity", "tempFile: " + tempFile.exists()); // This returns false!!!
if (tempFile != null) {
                                    tempImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PostItemActivity.this,
                                            "com.example.myapp.fileprovider", tempFile);
                                    //tempImageUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                                    Log.d("PostItemActivity", "tempFile: " + tempFile);
                                    Log.d("PostItemActivity", "tempFile uri: " + tempImageUri);
                                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempImageUri);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA1);
```

and in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
ImageView imageView=null;
            Bitmap bm=null;
            try {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA1) {
                    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postImageView1);
                    bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), tempImageUri);
                    //bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempImageUri.getPath());
                    imageFile = Storage.bitmapToFile(this, bm, "postFile1.jpg", imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    myFile=imageFile;
                }
```

and the errors I take:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
at com.example.myapp.PostItemActivity.onActivityResult(PostItemActivity.java:478) --> bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), tempImageUri);

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=31, result=0, data=null} to activity {...myapp.PostItemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Get rid of `bm`. Set `imageFile` to be `tempFile`, or use Java I/O to copy the file to `postFile1.jpg` Make sure that you hold onto `tempFile` in the saved instance state `Bundle`. There is no point in reading in the bitmap, then saving the bitmap back to a file, **when it is already a file in your internal storage**. Also, check `resultCode` to see if it is `RESULT_OK`. Some camera apps will not accept `content` `Uri` schemes for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, as even Google's own camera app did not support that until ~9 months ago.

Comment: The error occurs because it fails to create the bitmap from tempImageUri. Does this mean that MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT does not write the full-sized captured image to the file given by tempImageUri ?

Comment: You would have to find out for yourself. First, check to see if you got `RESULT_OK` -- if not, then you should not be expecting an image. Second, check to see if the file identified by `tempFile` exists. Use the `Uri` **only** for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Bear in mind that many camera apps have bugs, such as always ignoring `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: `tempFile.exists()); // This returns false`. Well then it has nothing to do with your file provider is it? I think the directory 'my_images' does not exists to begin with. I see no code where you check if it exists and if not create it.

Comment: `tempFile.createNewFile();`. Do not create the file yourself! You should only specify a path with the File object.

Comment: I don't get RESULT_OK and tempFile does not exist not even after onActivityResult is executed. I thought that with "new File(getFilesDir(),"my_images");" I create the directory my_images automatically. I can't find how to create it with respect to filepaths.xml.